# Block system commands in a C program

Tags: php, c, system, block, permission-denied

I am compiling and executing a C program that uses a PHP System Command on Windows XP Server.

If the C program contains a System command like `System("shutdown -a")` or any system command, then it turns my system down.

I want these kinds of commands to be denied.  How do I show "permission denied" as an output when a program tries to run a system command?

***Here is my code.***

**PHP script contains-**

```
system(gcc code.c -o out);    system(out.exe);
```

**IF C program contains**-

```
int main()     {      system("shutdown -r");   }
```

Is there a way to block those commands from being run?

Comment: Puh. That is really a hard question. What would qualify a system command? And which GCC version exactly?

Comment: Deleting "shutdown.exe" from System32 folder works as a turnaround ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Windows runas command**

You might be able to use windows `runas` command to run a command as a specific user.  And in that user's profile, set a list of white listed commands.  https://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows

**Roll your own command white list**

Create a list of commands in PHP or C that are allowed to be run through the C program, and if the command isn't on the approved list, it is denied. Or of you like to live dangerously, create a black list, and define a bunch of things you don't want run.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the simple answer is "Don't run as root" (then the user can only access files he/she has created, so not so much chance of doing damage)

The more sophisticated answer is to farm out the running of the code onto a virtual machine within the server. A virtual machine can be cloned from a template (or whatever the VM software calls such a thing) in fairly short time. Within a VM, the code running there has no access to the "REAL" machine that it runs on, so if the user wants to destroy his/her virtual machine, that is his/her problem - just have to request a "new virtual machine" before they can continue working.